# Why "*" works differently in different commands?

Tags: bash, shell, command, touch

For example, in `rm -r abc*` `"*"` means any string. However, if we use it in `touch abc* abcd* abcde*` (and we don't have any files in directory starting with abc or abcd or abcde) `"*"` means just a symbol, and files `abc* abcd* abcde*` will be created. If after that we will use `touch -m ab*` the modification time of files `abc* abcd* abcde*` will be changed.

Why in some cases `"*"` means any string, and in some cases it is just a symbol? how the computer know when to change it's meaning?

Comment: It's only a literal "*" when it doesn't match anything. That behavior can be changed in bash with `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: It works the same way actually, as `rm abc*` where there is no file matching `abc*` will give the error message `rm: cannot remove 'abc*': No such file or directory`. So if there is no match (whatever the command) the `*` will be just a symbol. Hence your question title is incorrect.

Comment: Important to note that the external commands have *nothing* to do with it: the **shell** handles globbing *before* lauching the command: see [3.1.1 Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a pattern such as `abc*` is used unquoted in the shell, the shell will try to match it against the available filenames (this is called "filename generation" but is often referred to as "globbing").  If it fails to match any filename, most `sh`-like shells will leave the pattern unexpanded and pass it to the utility as is.

Example:

```
$ touch xyz
$ touch abc*
$ tree
.
|-- abc*
`-- xyz

0 directory, 2 files
```

```
$ touch xyz*
$ tree
.
|-- abc*
`-- xyz

0 directory, 2 files
```

The `touch xyz*` command did *not* create a file called `xyz*`, because the filename `xyz` matched the pattern.  The `touch` utility was therefore called with the `xyz` filename.

In the `bash` shell, setting the `failglob` shell option with `shopt -s failglob` will make the shell complain if a shell glob does not match anything:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ touch 123*
bash: no match: 123*
```

The equivalent option is turned on by default in the `zsh` shell.

Setting the `nullglob` shell option in `bash` (or `NULL_GLOB` in `zsh`) would make the pattern disappear if it doesn't match a filename:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ touch fo*
usage: touch [-acm] [-d ccyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS[.frac][Z]] [-r file]
             [-t [[cc]yy]mmddHHMM[.SS]] file ...
```

(we get an error from `touch` since it was called without any arguments)

To guarantee that the pattern is used as a string (as it is), and *not* used for globbing, you should quote it:

```
$ touch "file*"
$ touch "file**"
$ touch "file***"
$ tree
.
|-- file*
|-- file**
`-- file***

0 directory, 3 files
```

Not quoting the filenames in this example would have given you only one file called `file*` (if the directory was initially empty), since the `file**` and `file***` patterns matches that first `file*` name.

Comment: _most shells_ should be _most Bourne-like shells_. That's a misfeature introduced by the Bourne shell, shells before the Bourne shell didn't have that issue and most non-Bourne-like shells (csh, tcsh, fish, (zsh)) don't have the problem.